# Sidebar using Flexbox: contained links not spreading out properly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I´m trying to make a side navigation bar using flexbox. The sidebar looks good, but I want the contained links to be spread out and take over the entire left of the screen. I try to do this using padding, but it ends up leaving a white space at the end. Any ideas?

```css
body {
  margin: auto 0;
}

#navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: solid;
  background: grey;
  height: 900px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid;
  padding: 80px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <header>"A dissertation on fast food"</header>
  <a class="nav-link" href="Steak">here</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="Steak">here</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="Steak">here</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="Steak">here</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="Steak">here</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having an overflow. You defined the height to be `900px` and for each box you have `160px` of padding-top/bottom so `800px` of padding and if we consider the border plus the content plus the header we will have more than `900px`.

Instead of padding you can use `flex:1` to stretch the elements then rely on flexbox inside them to center the text:

```css
body {
  margin: auto 0;
}

#navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: solid;
  background: grey;
  height: 900px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid;
  flex:1;
  /*to center the text*/
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <header>"A dissertation on fast food"</header>
  <a class="nav-link" href="Steak">here</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="Steak">here</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="Steak">here</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="Steak">here</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="Steak">here</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a flex container, instead of using padding for spacing, take advantage of flex features. The [**`flex-grow`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) property can distribute free space in the container evenly across all items.

```css
body {
  margin: auto 0;
}

#navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: solid;
  background: grey;
  height: 900px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid;
  /* padding: 80px; */
  flex-grow: 1; /* equal distribution of free space */
  
  /* for centering the text */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <header>"A dissertation on fast food"</header>
  <a class="nav-link" href="Steak">here</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="Steak">here</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="Steak">here</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="Steak">here</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="Steak">here</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you. Using "display: flex" and "Flex:1" definitely solved the issue. However, there seems to be some margin space around the entire sidebar that I can´t remove. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any margin space. The only space is the solid border you have set on `#navbar`.

Comment: You are right, I was opening an old version like an idiot. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Michael_B Could you check this one out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52017874/how-to-keep-flex-box-items-widths-independent-of-its-content ... note, the code needs to run in a local html file or else it won't behave, and if you compare the OP's question sample with their answer sample, you'll see how they act different...I suggested to use width combined with media query's (in my last comments), but you might see something else how-to, and have a _why_ available :)

Comment: @Michael_B The _why_, why `textarea` works I figured out, and commented at the question...and also about `align-items: stretch` for the _column items_, so I guess that actually answers the question....

Comment: @Michael_B And let me know when you read this and I'll delete these comments :)

Comment: I'll check when I'm on a desktop. Can't test much from a mobile device. @LGSon